# How to disable right click in html without using JavaScript?

Tags: html, css

I want to disable right click in my web page, JavaScript's provide that, but i need to do that without using any scripting Language.

Comment: You can't. But why disable right click?

Comment: Why can't you use a scripting language?

Comment: I'm trying some new features in HTML ...

Comment: If i use scripting Language, How can i do that? and which is best?

Comment: @MadhankumarBK Sorry. Without JS, you can't.

Comment: @MadhankumarBK just check my answer and try it out

Answer (score 4):

```
<body oncontextmenu="return false">
```

but actually it is javascript: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_oncontextmenu.asp

Answer (score 0):

```js
document.addEventListener("contextmenu", (e) => e.preventDefault(), false)
```